# Tuning a Strat a whole step down

Tags: guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I'd like to tune a Strat a whole step down, and I was wondering what gauge of strings I should use to get the same tension that I get in normal tuning with .010 strings.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try .011s.  Because they're heavier than .010s, they'll have higher tension, which might be enough to compensate for tuning them down a step.  But perhaps more importantly, they'll have a plain third string rather than a wound one, which will help keep the feel similar to the feel of the .010s.  I've tried .012s, but the wound third string feels very different.

Comment: .011-.052 is a good place to start. You can also try .012-.052 with an unwound G (LaBella Electrics Blues Heavy, for instance). I use these for tuning down 1 1/2 steps, which I find is somewhat slacker than standard E - but then again, I use .011-.052 for standard E.